# Where is npm run production output html file located?

Tags: html, laravel, vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix

I have an app built with `vue/laravel` and I need to edit something in its compiled `html` file. Since `npm run production` compiled the app on my machine and not on the server, I can't run `npm run prod` again on the server.

Where is the `html output file` located that gets compiled when the command is run? It's not in the `public` folder. Or is there another way to edit `vue/laravel` web apps after deploy? I hope it's possible because else I have to redeploy the whole web app just to change one html code line.

Comment: are you sure you didnt compile javascript (vue components) instead of html?

Comment: Does `npm run prod` compile HTML? "_I can't run npm run prod again on the server_" Why not? You should be able to run that command as often as you want

Comment: @Flame is the web app created from just the huge `app.js`?